# What is the difference between `injections` and `injectionSelector` in tmLanguage grammars?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, tmlanguage

I'm already familiar with the `injectionScope` property when writing an injection grammar for Visual Studio Code.

However, I've come across some grammars also using an `injections` property, for example here: https://github.com/pushqrdx/vscode-inline-html/blob/master/syntaxes/es6.inline.html.json, and I can't find any documentation about it. What is it used for?

Answer (score 1):

`injectionScope` controls where the main grammar from a file is injected. `"injectionSelector": L:source.js -comment -string` for example injects the file's main grammar into JavaScript code that is not a string or comment.

`injections` is a set of additional injection grammars. These are separate from the main file's grammar and take the form of a map from injection selectors to rules (a grammar). You can think of these as little injection grammars that are bundled into another grammar's file.